# How do I tell Resharper to look in a custom location for Partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, resharper

I have set up a project that has a custom ViewEngine that changes the traditional locations that Partials can be located. Previously, Resharper would let me F12 into my partial views, but that no longer works because Resharper thinks they don't exist even though they do. Can I do something to let Resharper know where to look for these files?

Comment: are all your view re-located or just your partials? Can you share your custom view engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have Resharper 8.2 installed. I would register custom `ViewEngine` in `global.asax` and it works fine.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //register custom ViewEngine
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyCustonViewEngine());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

and here is code snip for `MyCustonViewEngine`:

```
public class MyCustonViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyCustonViewEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/UI/MVC/Razor/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/UI/MVC/Razor/Shared/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        MasterLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;
        PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest  try this in a new project. If it still not work,maybe something wrong with Resharper settings or your codes.

Comment: This looks completely correct. Consider closing solution and restarting VS.

Comment: I think the issue is related to attempting to render partials without specifying a folder. I have opened an issue with JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-439479

Comment: Meanwhile, this solution technically IS correct, and Resharper is working with all my custom locations except that one case, so I will accept this answer.

Comment: any luck with this and Areas?